# Why is Route 53 forwarding traffic using the wildcard rule instead of the most specific one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a private hosted zone on Route 53 for the domain name:

```
dev.example.com
```

There's one CNAME record that routes traffic to an Elastic Load Balancer:

```
*.dev.example.com.  CNAME  xyz.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I tried adding the following record:

```
sftp.dev.example.com.  A  10.0.11.12
```

but traffic is always going through the load balancer.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming.  It would be better asked on https://serverfault.com/ .  But since I'm here anyway I'll ask the obvious question -- did you allow time for cached copies of the previous zone definition to age out before you tried to resolve `sftp.dev.example.com`?  (Also, I assume that `*.dev.example.ca.` is a typo for `*.dev.example.com.`.)

Comment: I think I did. Is is it the TTL (300 seconds)? (I corrected the typo) Thanks!